# Converting SQL statements with SUM, ROUND & COUNT into GQL

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm interacting with Google Datastore using the official PHP API SDK and "tomwalder/php-gds".

Google Datastore (and GQL) is perfect for 99% of the data I'm working with (few columns, consistent data structure, billions of rows), apart from a few queries.

The biggest problem I have, is with converting this SQL statement into GQL:

```
SELECT column_a, ROUND(SUM(column_b),0) as total_score, COUNT(column_a) as company_name 
FROM companies 
WHERE column_a <> '' AND column_c = '2015-05-30'
GROUP BY column_a 
ORDER BY total_score desc;
```

Without ROUND, SUM or COUNT available in GQL, is buffering the data to memory and using PHP to run the calculations the only option?
With 20MB of data per query, it doesn't seem the most efficient route to take. I really don't want to have to migrate to BigQuery, as I like the responsiveness of Datastore when reading from the data.

Comment: Have you considered [CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction) as an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use aggregate functions cheaply or easily with Datastore.

You need to approach the problem differently and maintain counts/sums etc. in your application layer.

It's a paradigm shift from traditional (powerful) MySQL flexibility.

I personally use both together.

CloudSQL for aggregate and reporting data updated by my application layer.

P.S. Thanks for using PHP-GDS!! I'm thinking about adding some aggregate helper utilities to that s head over to GitHub if you wanna raise a request.

Tom

Comment: Just to clarify, if you're going to store aggregate data in Datastore my suggestion is to maintain/pre-calculate in your application layer.

Comment: There's actually a decent comparison video from Google IO one year talking about Datastore vs SQL. I'll try and dig out the link...

Comment: if you don't precalculate everything, you could do it with MapReduce/dataflow but its costly.